# Any way to know the details of the bounty after it was awarded?

Tags: support, bounty

During the bounty period we can see who has opened the bounty for the question, as it can be a person who is not the question owner and also the reason why it was opened.

> This question has an open **bounty** worth **+200** reputation from **somename** ending **in 5 days**.
>   This question has not received enough attention.

But, after the bounty is awarded, we can only see the bounty amount below the score of the awarded post.

Is there any way, we can know if the bounty was awarded by the OP himself or it was just another person, possibly more information like when it was awarded, the reason of the bounty etc?

Comment: I'm quite sure that only the person who posts the bounty can select who gets it unless the bounty expires and it's automatically assigned. but this request is still good for when multiple bounties have been awarded to different answers on the same question (ie. someone have has 2 bounties (1x50 and 1x100) while another has only 1 bounty (1x150))

Comment: Try the revision-history. An exmple: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227809/revisions

Comment: @Deduplicator, Looks nice (at least for serving the purpose), but where is the link to go to the revision history for a specific question?

Comment: @Deduplicator, well, I found it. Sorry. But will that be available if the post was not edited at all, only bounty awarded?

Comment: [The timeline offers a lot more useful information](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227809/timeline#vote_98683127), though both the timeline and the revision history are always available if you manually enter the URL in the address bar `/posts/POST_ID/revisions` swap out `revisions` with  `timeline` to get the timeline.

Comment: On a lighter note, 1. Become mod 2. Go to http://stackoverflow.com/admin/accepted-bounties You'll get more than what you want :D

Comment: @TinyGiant Ah, my eyes! Look at that!

Comment: Too bad the custom bounty reason is not visible after the bounty is awarded. I've checked revisions and timeline.

Comment: @ArtjomB. There's an open [MSE feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110003/) for adding custom bounty remarks to a post's revision.

Answer (score 18):

This information is stored in the question instead of the answer. If you dig into the question history, you can see the reason for the bounties.

For example, for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/1542723), we can see in the history of the question that there was a bounty added by user Vaikesh with the reason "Authoritative reference":

[image: Bounty by Vaikesh]

### Meaning of bounty reasons:

**Authoritative reference needed**

Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

**Canonical answer required**

The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns.

**Current answers are outdated**

The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

**Draw attention**

This question has not received enough attention.

**Improve details**

The current answers do not contain enough detail.

**Reward existing answer**

One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

Comment: *Did not found this reason somewhere, plz edit post to fill in* ... Ahem, [really?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @BhargavRao Did not know that that question existed